Permissions for Synapse Stop/Start SQL pool -does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/sqlPools/read' over scope
I have got an util that runs a post to start/pause a SQL pool within Azure synapse, however I get the error below.
    {
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"AuthorizationFailed\",\"message\":\"The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/sqlPools/read' over scope '/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/my-workspace/sqlPools/my_sqlpool' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.\"}}",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "CheckPoolandStatus",
    "details": []
}

It is effectively saying that application spn which is named thesame as the synapse workspace doesnt have permissions ? What have I done ?
I have granted read permissions on the synapse RBAC workspace, I have also granted the synapse administrator role on the synapse studio RBAC.
I saw a similar question here and followed the instructions, didnt work. Also saw another here
Any ideas on the actual required permissions ?
